# Keyboard-layout changes on login screen - only after "manually" logging out

Tags: keyboard-layout, system-settings, input-language

Weirdly, my keyboard layout changes from qwerty to qwertz on the login screen after logging out of a session. Which makes it a bit weird to enter a password that contains special characters. It's normal after login, so it's not a big deal, but I still would like to fix this. This doesn't happen when locking the screen, then it stays qwerty. Does anyone have a hint which file this error might have crept in?

Comment: What does `/etc/default/keyboard` look like? (Please answer by editing your question.)

Comment: this really was the source of the error. it contained a value for the german layout. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In GNOME 42 running GDM login manager, `localectl` told me `VC Keymap: n/a`.

Running `sudo localectl set-x11-keymap dk` set the login screen layout to Danish.

See further [this GNOME help page](https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/keyboard-layout.html.en)